# How to use array with LIKE with whereIn to retrieve eloquent rows in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have an array

```
//dynamically generated. dynamic number of elements
$keywords = ['google', 'youlense'];
```

For a exactly matching values of `$keywork` mapping to row in content column, i can do following:

```
$result = \App\Table::where(function($query){
    $query->whereIn('content', $keywords);
});
```

and the result would be somewhat

```
select * from tables where content IN ('google', 'youlense');
```

but I want to use `LIKE` operator so the result may be like

```
select * from tables where content LIKE ('%google%', '%youlense%');
```

I know that is not allowed in mysql but can some one recommend a simple and clean technique to handle this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use `orWhere` method for every keyword and it will equivalent for `whereIn`. The code will look like:

```
$result = \App\Table::where(function($query){
    $query->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', '%google%')
          ->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', '%youlense%')
          -> and so on;
});

$result = \App\Table::where(function($query) use($keywords){
    foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
        $query->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', "%$keywords%")
    }
});
```

*Note:* gotten query can work very slowly.

Comment: thanks but that would work if i knew there are only two elements. In real scenario, this array would be dynamically generated and there would be dynamic number of items. My mistake i didn't mention that.

Comment: Sure, just use foreach. I will update the answer. But it can be slow. @Eirtaza

Comment: number of queries run = elements in $keyword... m i right?

Comment: No, number of conditions in one query.

Comment: check the answer below... it would be 1 query. Both answers are 100 % same i dont know which one to mark as correct answer. stuck

Comment: Well, it's up to you but usually the earliest one is marked if the answers are the same. @Eirtaza

Comment: it only returns the results matched in last loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that will basically do the following :

```
public function searchByKeywords(array $keywords = array()){
    $result = \App\Table::where(function($query) use ($keywords){
         foreach($keywords as $keyword){
              $query = $query->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");
         }
         return $query;
    });
    return $result->get(); // at this line the query will be executed only
                           // after it was built in the last few lines
}
```

Comment: if there are three elements in $keyword, how many mysql queries would it run? 1 or 3

Comment: one, because this is not running queries, this is only building it, later when you get the result the query will be executed all at once

Comment: i agree, i am stuck which answer to mark as correct. please decide among urselves with andrej

Comment: I updated the answer , never mind man :) it is ok just accept his answer since he wrote it first :)